# Bison print rule printing backwards

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

Hi I am making a parser for a simple programming language for an assignment.

Here are my bison rules

```
program:
    start var_decl_list main statement_list end

start:
    START EOS {printf("Start")};

var_decl_list: 
    var_decl_list variable_declaration | variable_declaration;

variable_declaration:
    S VAR_NAME EOS { add_variable($1, $2); };

main: 
    MAIN EOS {printf("Main")};

statement_list:
    statement_list statement | statement;

statement:
  move_statement
  | add_statement
  | input_statement
  | print_statement
  ;

move_statement:
    MOVE NUMBER TO VAR_NAME EOS { int_to_var($2, $4) }
    | MOVE VAR_NAME TO VAR_NAME EOS { move_var_to_var($2, $4) };

add_statement:
    ADD NUMBER TO VAR_NAME EOS { add_int_to_var($2, $4) }
    | ADD VAR_NAME TO VAR_NAME EOS { add_var_to_var($2, $4) };

input_statement:
    INPUT input_list;

input_list:
    VAR_NAME EOS { find_variable($1)};
    | VAR_NAME SEMICOLON input_list {printf("INPUT statement")};

print_statement:
    PRINT print_list;

print_list:
    VAR_NAME EOS {print_variable($1)}
    | TEXT EOS {print_text($1)}
    | VAR_NAME SEMICOLON print_list {print_variable($1)}
    | TEXT SEMICOLON print_list {print_text($1)};
end:
    END EOS {printf("End")};
```

My Problem is with the print statement.

If I print the following:

```
PRINT "I have ";XY;" apples".
```

I get this output

```
" apples"35"I have "
```

What am I doing wrong with print statement rule?

Comment: When it processes the recursive `print_list`, it prints that before it returns to the main production. You need to recurse from right to left, not left to right.

Comment: Changing it to ````print_list VAR_NAME SEMICOLON```` and ````print_list TEXT SEMICOLON```` causes a syntax error

Comment: You need `print_list SEMICOLON VAR_NAME` and `print_list SEMICOLON TEXT`. After processing a (piece of a) print_list, see if the next things are a semicolon then something else printable.

Comment: This is why real compilers don't do code generation/execution in the parser. They generate a parse tree, and then a separate phase generates code from that.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `print_list` rule is right-recursive, it will reduce the items from right to left, and thus print them in right-to-left order.

Use a left-recursive rule if you want the reductions (and processing) to occur left to right.